# Start NGINX from python script

Tags: python, nginx, subprocess

I need to start/stop nginx from my python script quite frequently for test purposes.

When I do

```
from subprocess import Popen
process = Popen(['/usr/sbin/nginx', '-c', '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'])
print process.pid    # prints 21621
```

As a result `process.pid` is equal to some pid.

However, when I look to `ps ax | grep nginx` output, that pid is zombie, then disappears. However there is an nginx master process who's pid is greater than original pid by 1.

> ```
> 21621 pts/0    Z+     0:00 [nginx] <defunct>
> 21622 ?        Ss     0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
> 21623 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
> 21624 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
> ```

Is there any special magic in starting nginx from python script?

Comment: If your conf file has `daemon on` then it will fork off a separate process to start in the background.  You likely want `daemon off` so you get the actual PID of the NGINX process since you're backgrounding it yourself.

Comment: @Joe, not there's no `daemon on` there. However there is a `worker_processes auto` setting. Does it have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

you may can use `setsid`. use this code

```
process = Popen(['setsid', '/usr/sbin/nginx', '-c', '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'])
```

`man setsid` for more info

Comment: with almost the same result: `22542 ?        Zs     0:00 [nginx] <defunct>`

Comment: what about creating `systemd` service and `start` or `stop` it from python?

Comment: systemd has some peculiarities which prevent me from using it , like it doesn't stop nginx timely, where there is a lot of processes running. It also goes to swap deeply under some load patterns